# Setting background color in DataGridComboxColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want to set the backgroundcolor in a DataGridComboxColumn.
I tried with xaml using

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Auswahl1" TextBinding="{Binding Auswahl1S, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=AuswahlL, ElementName=testdialog}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Auswahl1Background}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
   <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=AuswahlL, ElementName=testdialog}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I also tried in code behind:

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn col4 = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
col4.Header = "Auswahl4";
col4.ItemsSource = AuswahlL;
col4.TextBinding = new Binding("Auswahl4S");
Binding b = new Binding("Auswahl1Background");
Style style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(ComboBox));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ComboBox.BackgroundProperty, b));
col4.ElementStyle = style;
```

None is working and I have no idea what is wrong here.

Thanks
Walter

Comment: Combobox background cannot be changed unless you modify it's `ControlTemplate` because background of border is set explicitly in it's default template. Even simple `<Combobox Background="Red"/>` won't work.

Comment: Check this link for the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800543/how-add-background-colors-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn-ltems-wpf/32712891#32712891

Answer (score 0):

use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. So that you can directly set the Controls thing what ever you want..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Auswahl1">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxColumn">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                           <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=AuswahlL, ElementName=testdialog}" />
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Auswahl1Background}" />
                     </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
           </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

or else you could use StyleSelector and Set Background for that particular GridCell. [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx)

You can follow the same thing mentioned in the following [link..](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0687591b-1ef8-48bb-a598-09f4b4a05cb4/wpf-datagrid-row-selector-xaml-syntax-question?forum=wpf)

Comment: This definitely not answer OP's question. `Background` of combobox can't be changed without modifying `ControlTemplate` of Combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it'll help you.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```