# How add Background colors in DataGridComboBoxColumn ltems wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

i try in this way but its not working.

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ResourcesList}" />
                        <Setter Property="ComboBox.Foreground" Value="{Binding TypeOfEntry, Converter={StaticResource DisplayValueToBrushConverter}}"/>
                         <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Background" Value="SpringGreen"/>Value="Violet"/>
                    </Style>
```

Comment: Were you surprised that the *item* `Background` didn't change when you set the `ComboBox.Background` property?

Comment: please explain. i am not following you i try  <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Background" Value="SpringGreen"/> this one its not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set background color of ComboBox while editing DataGridComboBoxColumn, you can use this method

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I tried this and it is working fine.