# how change font color in DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried the following way.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ResourcesList}"  />
                        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Foreground" Value="{Binding TypeOfEntry, Converter={StaticResource DisplayValueToBrushConverter}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Background" Value="SpringGreen"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

nothing changes. Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Check this link for the answer


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800543/how-add-background-colors-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn-ltems-wpf/32712891#32712891

Answer (score 0):

I did these changes, now its working

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ResourcesList}" />

                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Background" Value="SlateBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="SpringGreen"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```